# OpenCart - Trying to Update Product Table from Front End

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I have values that I am pulling from my OpenCart (mysql) database, I give them to a form the user can then submit and use to update their product table. However when I run the below code, 1) no errors come up, and 2) when I check mysql database I see the column but it remains 0 instead of the value I want (e.g. 1, 4, 5, etc.).

Model:

```
public function unit_id_update() {

    $product_id = $this->db->getLastId();

    $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "product SET unit_class_id = " . $this->db->$unit_type_id .  " WHERE product_id = " . (int)$product_id);   
}

public function unit_id_request() {
    $w_data = $this->db->query("SELECT weight_class_id FROM  ". DB_PREFIX ." weight_class_description");
        if (!$w_data) {
        die(mysql_error());
        }
        else { 
        return $w_data; 
        }
}
```

Controller:

```
    $this->load->model('catalog/product'); //where functions are located
    $another_var = $this->model_catalog_product->unit_id_request();

    $this->data['weight_var'] = $another_var;
    $this->data['kg'] = $another_var->rows[0]['weight_class_id'];
    $this->data['g'] = $another_var->rows[1]['weight_class_id'];
    $this->data['lb'] = $another_var->rows[2]['weight_class_id'];
    $this->data['oz'] = $another_var->rows[3]['weight_class_id'];

    if (isset($this->request->post['unit_type_id'])) {
        $this->data['unit_type_id'] = $this->request->post['unit_type_id'];
    }
    else {
        $this->data['unit_type_id'] = '';
    }
```

View:

```
<tr>
    <td><?php echo "Unit Type"; ?></td></tr>
    <td><select name="unit_type_id">
        <optgroup label="<?php echo "Weight"; ?>">        
            <option value="<?php echo $lb; ?>" >lb</option>
            <option value="<?php echo $oz; ?>">oz</option>       
            <option value="<?php echo $kg; ?>">kg</option>
            <option value="<?php echo $g; ?>">g</option>              
        </optgroup>
    </select></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Believe me, you do not want this `die(mysql_error());` in production. Handle the case in different way (e.g. returning an empty array and logging the error instead).
2. The problem is the whole `unit_id_update()` method. You should be passing the `$product_id` and `$unit_type_id` variables as arguments from your controller (that is handling the POST request).

The method should look like:

```
public function unit_id_update($product_id, $unit_type_id) {
    $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "product SET unit_class_id = " . (int)$unit_type_id .  " WHERE product_id = " . (int)$product_id);
}
```

Comment: I added both parameters to the function, and it still isn't making any changes to the database. I also tried `INSERT` instead of `UPDATE`.

Comment: And can you debug that there are values being passed over to the model method? `UPDATE` is what you want to use.

Comment: I am giving you the answer because I indeed forgot to pass the parameters `$product_id` and `$unit_type_id` to my function. I believe your answer to be correct, however I think something went wrong because this was an xml file I was trying to add an extension on to. I went to `catalog/model['account/customerpartner']` which the page I was on `catalog/controller/['account/addproduct']` was already loaded. And added a few lines for my `INSERT` and `UPDATE` database functions that were written similar to the above function.

Answer (score -2):

Try inserting a space before 'product' in the query in unit_id_update() and check.

```
$this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . " product SET unit_class_id = " . $this->db->$unit_type_id .  " WHERE product_id = " . (int)$product_id);
```

Comment: Nope, this is incorrect answer. Probably comes out from low or no knowledge of OpenCart platform.